# I want to add characters to the beginning and end of all lines in the txt document at once

Tags: txt

I have a txt document of 200k+ lines. I want to add different characters to all carriage returns and different characters to all line breaks. How can I do it?

Comment: For what programming language? What have you tried? Any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use EMEditor for handling files with big data.

- You can select all lines, split them for single lines.
- You'll have multiple cursors and whatever you'll write will be written for all the cursors.
- Press end or home to move to the line start or end.

Comment: @EKA select all -> Edit option on toolbar -> Vertical Selection.